# Why does dragging this jpanel create a screen tearing effect?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

When dragging these "tiles" which are jPanel objects over each other or another Jpanel, they leave an outline of the path through the object.

I've tried using the repaint function on the panels every time they are dragged or clicked on by an eventListener but this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

```
/// tile class
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Tile extends JPanel {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 /** Tile objects to be added to the game board.
  * The constructor should eventually create the maze pattern
  * and determine the tiles initial location. 
  */
 DragListener drag;
 public int ID;
 Tile()
 {
  drag = new DragListener();

  this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
  this.addMouseListener( drag );
  this.addMouseMotionListener( drag );
 }

 public void paint(Graphics t)
 {
  t.setFont(new Font("Ariel",0,18));
  FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics(new Font("Ariel",0,18));
  String id = Integer.toString(ID);
  t.setColor(Color.white);
  t.fillRect(0, 0, 80, 80);
  t.drawRect(0, 0, 80, 80);
  t.setColor(Color.black);
  t.drawString(id,5,20);
 }
}


// my drag listener class

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter {

        Point location;
        MouseEvent pressed;
        int tileID;
        int [] gridPos;
        int  initialX, initialY;
        boolean moved = false;
        int buffer =20;

        int [] gridMidX = {327,327,327,327,407,407,407,407,488,488,488,488,568,568,568,568};
        int [] gridMidY = {260,341,421,501,260,341,421,501,260,341,421,501,260,341,421,501};
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
        {
            pressed = me;
            Component component = me.getComponent();
            location = component.getLocation(location);
            if (!moved) {
            initialX = location.x;
            initialY = location.y; 
            moved = true;
            }
        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
        {

            Component component = me.getComponent();
            location = component.getLocation(location);
            int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
            int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
            component.setLocation(x, y);

         }
       public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
           Component component = me.getComponent();
           location = component.getLocation(location);
           int x = location.x;
           int y = location.y;
           int p[] = findSnap(x,y);
           int z = p[0];
           int a = p[1];

            component.setLocation(z, a);
        }
        public int[] findSnap(int x, int y )
        {

         int xp=initialX, yp=initialY;
         int buff =50;
         int pos[] = new int[2];
         if(y>(gridPos[1]+buff) || y < (gridPos[0]-buff)|| x< (gridPos[2] - buff)|| x>(gridPos[3]+buff))
         {
            xp = initialX;
            yp = initialY;

         }
         else{
             //setGrid();
             for(int i=0; i<16; i++) {
                int a = gridMidX[i];
                int b = gridMidY[i];
                int hold [] =  {x,y};
                 if(check(a,b,hold )) {

                    pos[0] = a;
                    pos[1]= b;
                     return pos;
                 }
             }

         }
         pos[0] = xp;
         pos[1] = yp;
         return pos;
        }

        // we need to call in tile

        public boolean check (int e, int f, int [] grid) {

            int nearY,nearX;
            nearX = Math.abs(e-grid[0]);
            nearY = Math.abs(f-grid[1]);            
            if (nearX <=70 && nearY <= 70) {

                return true;
                }

            return false;
        }
}
```

The tiles should be able to be dragged across another jPanel and not leave a trail of where they were dragged. They only do this when crossing another Jpanel, inside a JFrame, they don't seem to have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void paint(Graphics t)
```

Don't override paint().

Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent(...)` method.

Then the first statement in the method should be:

```
super.paintComponent(...);
```

to make sure the background get painted every time to prevent painting artifacts.